# computed observable not binding to field label from input field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Within an file I have to html elements one a label and one an input field.

```
<label class="reportNameTextBox" title="Click to edit report name"  data-bind="text: Name() == null || Name().trim().length == 0 ? '[ Click to Enter Report Name ]' : Name(), css: { 'noData': Name() == null || Name().trim().length == 0 }"></label>
<input class="editInput" type="text" data-bind="value: Name" />
```

both are bound to a Knockout viewmodel titled report that has a property Name

Within the viewmodel I am trying to create a computed observable that will constrain the characters to 255

```
report.Name = ko.computed(function () {
  return report.Name().substring(0, 255);
});
```

The problem I am having is prior to creating the computed observable the bindings worked fine. Entering values into the input field would be reflected in the label. Once I created the observable. The binding between the two fields is broken but still retained within the input field?

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created computed with the same name as observable therefore ko overrides it. Use another name for computed e.g. `NameFormatted`:

```
report.NameFormatted = ko.computed(function () {
  return report.Name().substring(0, 255);
});
```